Mean value of a Dataframe comes out transposed
I am iterating over serval files and for each file I get a data frame.

I then calculate mean for each data frame using following.
BinA_Data.mean(axis=0,skipna=True, numeric_only=True))

But the results I get is a series where indexes are the column names like

But actually I want to have mean value show up with column names "as is" like

Later on I want to concatenate the mean calculated for each file to show something like this.

I tried using transpose() but still the mean always shows with column names as index and I loose the column name which I want to preserve. Any suggestions?
Above is a sample data actual mean not match with the mean values shown.

Example Code
You should not provide samples of your examples as images, but rather provide a minimal and reproducible example.
Since the result generated by your code(BinA_Data.mean(axis=0,skipna=True, numeric_only=True)) is a series, we will generate a simple series s as a sample
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3], index=['A', 'B', 'C'])

s
A    1
B    2
C    3
dtype: int64


Code
Since the series is one-dimensional, it cannot be transposed. Convert to a data frame and try transpose.
out = s.to_frame().T

out
    A   B   C
0   1   2   3


Don't use sum but rather agg with a list of the aggregation functions to keep the DataFrame format:
df.agg(['sum'])

Or to also compute the mean as a second row:
df.agg(['sum','mean'])

Example:
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], columns=['A','B','C'])

   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6

df.agg(['sum'])

     A  B  C
sum  5  7  9

df.agg(['sum','mean'])

        A    B    C
sum   5.0  7.0  9.0
mean  2.5  3.5  4.5

